# Java get generic typed object

Tags: java, c#, generics, casting

Is there any equivalent in Java to C# of getting generic typed object for ex.:

```
public T getValue<T>()
{
     return(T)_myValue; // object _myValue = "";
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean. That code, with the `<T>` moved, would be valid Java. It wouldn't *really* cast at execution time within the method, and would give a warning, but it would be valid Java...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
public <T> T getValue(Class<T> tClass)
```

There is no universal type conversion in Java.  You can cast at runtime, but only if the object is that type already.